# AWS redirect .net, .co.uk and .org to .com

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

I own multiple domains (.com, .co.uk, .net, .org) which all have the same name. These domains are registered at 123-reg (https://www.123-reg.co.uk/). I am hosting a static website in AWS using S3 + Cloudfront and I've set up alias records for .com in Route 53. All is working fine but I want to be able to redirect all the other, non-.com domains to .com.

I have seen [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/) on AWS support but the 'Redirect requests' option in S3 only allows you to specify one target domain which does not help me.

[image]

Currently I am using the 'Use this bucket to host a website' option FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article mentioned is correct. You'll have to create a new s3 bucket for each new domain url and setup the Redirect requests for each new bucket.

1. Create new S3 Buckets that have the same name as the domain name
2. Create multiple route53 records that point to the S3 buckets
3. For each bucket, go to properties, static website hosting and setup redirect requests.

And this should work.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I guess this makes sense, I was hoping this wouldn't be the answer! Seems like such an ugly solution. Is this the only way?

Comment: It's the only solution if you want to stay serverless unfortunately. Their are other solutions by using an ec2 instance with nginx installed, but that would beat the purpose...

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have gone with your solution which has worked.

Comment: Is it possible to create a single S3 bucket called say 'redirectto.example.com' and point each of the route53 records to this single S3 bucket?  You'll still need a route53 hosted zone per domain but at least it will simplify the S3 side of things